# MySql View - Value from one column where some other column is max

Tags: mysql, view, subquery

I have Table1 and Table2 related on Table1.ID.  There can be zero or more Table2 records for a given Table1.ID.  I have a view where I want to get Table2.Value where Table2.ID is max for a given Table1.ID.  A friend suggested a derived table, but that requires a subquery in the from clause, and MySQL doesn't like that.  Are there any other ways to do this?  I tried setting up a secondary view to take the place of the subquery, but it seems very slow.  I also tried using a having clause to test Table2.ID = MAX(Table2.ID), but it doesn't recognize the column unless I put it into the group by, which screws everything else up.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? It should be just fine with subqueries if you're using 5.x

Comment: I'm on v5.0.  The docs I've read and the error I get indicate that subqueries in the from clause are not allowed in a view.  Is that only in 5.0?

Comment: It's an open bug in MySQL: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=12755

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*, t2a.*
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2a
 ON (t1.table1_id = t2a.table1_id)
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2b
 ON (t1.table1_id = t2b.table1_id AND t2a.table2_id < t2b.table2_id)
WHERE t2b.table2_id IS NULL
 AND t1.table1_id = ?;
```

Comment: Works great!  Much quicker than the secondary view.  Thanks.  Any performance concerns I should look out for with this method?  With regard to table sizes or indexing or anything?

Comment: Well, you should always analyze with EXPLAIN any query you need to have good performance, and try to make sure it's using indexes well and not doing filesort/temporary table.  But this query is about as scalable as you can get in a normalized database.